# Mirrorizing the swing components

Tags: java, swing, layout, orientation, mirroring

I am using `Left-To-Right (LTR)` as default Component Orientation for laying out the swing components in JPanels. Now I need to mirrorize all the components in the panel and display them from `Right-To-Left(RTL)`. This will be used for Arabic Locale.

For example the order of components: `"label-textbox-button"` must turn the new order: `"button-textbox-label"` without changing their vertical positions.

`setComponentOrientation` and `applyComponentOrientation` methods are not working because the layout managers I used, does not support these methods. These methods are supported by `FlowLayout`, `GridLayout` etc. I'm using absolute coordinates like this :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(0, 50, 800, 100);
JButton button1 = new JButton("Cancel");
button1.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 120);
panel.add(button1);
```

when mirrorize, bounds of button will be : (600, 60, 100, 120);

[Here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Node+Orientation+in+JavaFX) is a clear sample about what I want but that is `JavaFX` version of it. I also do not want to recreate components screens. I just want to repaint and redisplay them according to Locale. So looking for any `Java API` or open library, if there are any. Thanks for your suggestions and help about where to find it if possible.

Comment: _because the layout managers I used, does not support these_ then use a manager that does ;-) Which one is it, btw - all (?) core support RToL and can't remember seeing a third-party that doesn't

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Comment: sorry for my inexperience. @kleopatra I'm using absolutelayout and that does not support the RTL orientation. Here is some [explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#orientation)

Comment: repeating: use a LayoutManager that suits your needs (that is that doesn't force _you_ to do the heavy lifting), nothing else will really help you

Comment: thanks @kleopatra I got it but I'm already looking for some other utility, API etc. that makes RTL Orientation without using LayoutManager or with using AbsoluteLayout. Otherwise, I may have to create a mirrorizer CustomLayout by implementing LayoutManager.

Comment: I have hundreds of forms constructed already and a suitable Layout Manager did not used mostly. So I reversed controls manually. GridLayout has the feasibility for mirrorizing according to orientation but Flow Layout don't. I finished the task by writing a general code that controls the type of layout and mirrorizes it according to this type. Thank you for your help.